# Why can't I assign a value inside begin catch block / TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I try to assign a value to a variable inside a begin catch block. It says `could not be evaluated`:

[image: Error message]

I want to collect all those records' ids and at the end of process, log them.

```
OPEN FilesCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM FilesCursor INTO @recordId;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION;
        BEGIN TRY
            SET XACT_ABORT ON;
                SET @insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO '+ @remoteLinkedServerName +'.PatlatDB.dbo.TestTab...';

                SET @updateQuery = '...';

                EXECUTE(@insertQuery);
                EXECUTE(@updateQuery);
            SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                SET @errorIds += ',' + CAST(@recordId AS VARCHAR);
                SET @errorMessage += '|' + CAST((SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()) AS VARCHAR);
            END;
        END CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
FETCH NEXT FROM FilesCursor INTO @recordId;
END;
CLOSE FilesCursor;
DEALLOCATE FilesCursor;
```

Comment: You should check `XACT_STATE` instead of `TRANCOUNT` in catch block.

Comment: tried and failed. IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 this didnt help too, to let me asign the value.

Comment: Noticed that you enable `XACT_ABORT` option - you should avoid it if you'd like to detect active transaction in catch block. Just try to comment lines with `xact_abort`.

Comment: And the real obstacle to collecting values I guess is casting to `varchar` with not size defined. For `int` it will need 10 symbols. And check out how you declared `@errorIds` variable. Is it varchar with no size too?

Comment: First, When i remove XACT_ABORT, remote server returns an error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399361/archiving-data-between-linked-servers-transaction-issue

And the second, yup it is, DECLARE @errorIds VARCHAR(MAX);

Comment: `XACT_ABORT` rollbacks entire transaction. You can keep it for whatever purpose but you are attempting to check trancount after exception. Did you check your code ever enters block with errids processing? "Second", casting to varchar with no size defined cuts your values to 1(one) symbol.

Comment: Im transferring records to a server from another server and for some reason(I dont know why) it seems like im obligated to use XACT_ABORT to work on linked servers. And i dont know why but when i set first time values for the variables, it did worked. have no clue.

Comment: Did you check whether your code enters `IF TRANCOUNT>0` block when error occurs? You may put a simple `print 'test'` there. Did you fix casting to varchar? What results to you get in the end? NULL, empty string, what is there?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yup, I did all my controls. If any error occurs, it gets rollback and collects recordIds, if not then transfers records and commits and at final it logs recordIds. Also as how you did said I change all my castings and defined size for them such as --> SET @errorIds += ',' + CAST(@recordId AS VARCHAR(MAX)). Its all done, thanks alot.